# jpa - Override Id Auto Generating before/after saving to repository for testing?

Tags: java, jpa

So, I have some @Entity class that auto generates an Id

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
```

but, the problem is that during testing, I want to save specific ID's. I can create an object and give it any id I want but, unfortunately as soon as I call any save operation

```
save()
saveAll()
saveAndFlush()
```

to the repository, a new & different id is generated and takes the place of the one I assigned which will ruin all of my testing.

Any recommendations as a workaround ? I don't have access to change the actual entity or repository classes. Is there a way I can override the repository save implementation but, only for some test repo ?

Comment: have you found any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can be done.

You want to test the database connection/save with an IT test?
If not you can mock your repository to avoid a save with an unwanted id.
Then you write your asserts to... assert what you expect.

Why do you want to avoid and auto generated id during test?

Comment: My tests are integration tests & use h2 as an in-memory dbms but, I think you are right that with that type of test it is not possible. I will probably take your recommendation and avoid this type of testing and instead opt for mocking out what the repo will return.

Comment: For IT tests, i'm a beginner, when i didn't want the test data to stay in db, after the test, i launch a delete(), or deleteById(), something like that. Of course you have to retrieve the data before to know the id with a findByChoosenProperty(theProperty);

It might not be a very pro or clean solution but it worked for me .